# How to make Azure Storage Static Website URL single-use

Tags: azure, azure-storage, static-site

I am setting up a static website on Azure Storage that will basically be a single page where a user must fill in a value and then press a button. I generated a SAS that expires after 24 hours, but the other part I am struggling with is to limit access to the generated URL to a single-use only.

I've tried reading through the Azure docs on Microsoft's site but I couldn't find a way to do it

Basically I expect a user to click on the link and it should take them to the html page. But if they try and click on it a second time, it should throw an error saying that they cannot access the page or just give like a 403 response

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to define a SAS URL with number of times it can be used. As long as SAS token associated with the URL is valid, a user will be able to use that URL.

For this, you would need to use some kind of middleware. Essentially instead of taking user directly to SAS URL link, you take them to a separate link with a unique token. When the user lands there, you check if the token has already been used (by looking up in a database) and then take appropriate action i.e. either allow the user to the final destination or deny access.